# Datastage 11.5 Exception Handling

Tags: datastage

Am using Datastage 11.5, Created parallel jobs but I need to handle the exceptions and the details should sent in a mail.

1. How to add exception handling for parallel jobs ?
2. How to send the exception details in mail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very general question so you just get a general answer.

Check out Sequences and Mail Notification activity there - this is the way to go. There is an option to add job details on failure there.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i can see the mail notification only for sequence jobs not in parallel jobs.. how to do that ? and there is no objects in palatte to choose exception for parallel jobs whereas sequential have those options by default..

Comment: Do not mix sequential and sequences - sequential is a non-parallel job but a Sequence is a control structure to run jobs. I was talking about Sequences - and those could run parallel jobs and mail notifications.

Comment: thanks Michael, i got this difference now. I tried to send a mail from notification activity, getting a message that mail sent but I didn't receive any mails. how to solve this ?

Comment: Check with the admin team to see if the mail server is correct and accessible frm your server